# Grials: Image tag?

Tags: grails, web

I was trying to load image dynamically using:

```
<g:img src="${resource(dir:'images/products', file:product?.photo)}" alt="" />
```

but it gives some thing like this in out put

```
<img src="/static/images" src="/static/images/products/2017-02-05 16:46:32.599.jpg" alt="" />
```

Comment: its on grails 3.2.5

Comment: `resource(dir` seriously ? on grails 3.2.5  ? haha try `<asset:image src="products/photo${id}"/>`.  You are referring to ancient grails examples

Comment: Actually image is inside web-app directory. And I couldn't find any other solution.

Comment: https://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html  search for web-app on this page. It clearly states both are supported

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are looking at old documentation. Grails 3 uses the asset pipeline plugin by default.

You should be using the following syntax instead:
`<asset:image src="yourFile.png"/>`

The documentation for the Asset Pipeline plugin has all the needed information, the following is a direct link to the pertinent information.
 http://bertramdev.github.io/grails-asset-pipeline/guide/usage.html#linking

Comment: asset tag cannot load image from web-app directory.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try this
var customImageurl = "products/product?.photo";function xxx(){document.getElementById("loadImage").src = customImageurl;}window.onload = function(){loadGraphics();};`